# Open command line in running service

Tags: server, services, minecraft

So I made a minecraft server on my RaspberyPi 4 on Rasberry OS. I created a service so I can run it in the background. But now I wanna know if I can "open" the command line to run some admin commands, while its running and to check the log. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: [This post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1419787/968501) is related and might help ... Not specifically about Raspberry Pi OS though, but similar question.

Comment: yeah, you can. Do you know where the log file is written to ? If so, simply open terminal app, `cd <path_to_log_file>` (`cd` command changes directory) and tail the log file by typing `tail -80f <log_file_name.log>`. I am not sure what you mean by admin commands, but I don't see why you cannot run commands, admin or not at the same time ... Linux is a multitasking OS.